# cómo arreglar el formato de las fechas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

he creado una función para sacar un rango de fechas de dos DateEntry en tkinter. El problema, es que el método **"get_date()"** los saca en formato Año/Mes/Día y eso no me sirve ya que intento hacer un query en mysql. El método **"get()"** a secas debería de sacarlo bien pero la función no acepta **"date1.get()"** cómo parámetro. Necesito que el output sea: Mes/Dia/Año. Si alguien sabe cómo puedo resolverlo, gracias.

```
def date_range(start,stop):
    global dates # If you want to use this outside of functions
     
    dates = []
    diff = (stop-start).days
    for i in range(diff+1):
        day = start + timedelta(days=i)
        dates.append(day)
    if dates:
    
        print(dates) # Print it, or even make it global to access it outside this
    

date1 =tkinter.DateEntry(ventana_reportes)
date1.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=10,pady=10)

date2 =tkinter.DateEntry(ventana_reportes)
date2.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=10,pady=10)

date_range(date1.get_date(),date2.get_date())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contexto: El OP tiene una columna fecha en formato text, y no creo que quiera cambiarlo a esta altura. Eso hace que esta solución se centre en funcionar con este formato de base de datos. Ver el final de la pregunta para una solución para columnas de tipo date.

---

#### Por que no sirve .get()

La razón por la que no te funciona con `.get()` es que para poder crear un rango de fechas requieres las facilidades que ofrece el módulo datetime.
Y cuando conviertes en cadena un objeto `datetime.date`, lo devuleve en formato `%y-%m-%d`.

#### Solución

Cuando obtengas la fecha con los dias sumados, conviertelo en el mismo formato de fecha que tienes en la tabla.

```
def date_range(start,stop):
    global dates # If you want to use this outside of functions
     
    dates = []
    diff = (stop-start).days
    for i in range(diff+1):
        day = start + timedelta(days=i)
        dates.append(day.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"))
    if dates:
    
        print(dates)
```

No estoy seguro del formato de la fecha, pero cualquier cosa podés modificarlo con ayuda de [esta tabla](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Esto, finalmente, generará una lista de cadenas compatible con tu columna.

#### Solución para columnas tipo date

Si la columna es tipo date, no se necesita trabajar con un rango de fechas que da saltos de a un día. Podemos comparar la fecha diciendo que sea mayor a cierta fecha y menor o igual a cierta otra:

```
SELECT fecha FROM tabla WHERE fecha > '2020-12-13' AND fecha <= '2020-12-15'
```

Esto es mucho mejor que crear en memoria un rango de fechas y pasarselo a una consulta.

Comment: Gracias @DanteS. Ahora sí funciona cómo debe funcionar, el problema es que mysql no acepta listas cómo parámetros para un query

Comment: De nada! c: Tendrás que usar una fusión entre parametros y formateo de cadenas.

Comment: Ya hice otra pregunta. pero lo voy a googlear a ver si lo resuelvo